# Comparing Enum Entries - Java

Tags: java, inheritance, enums

Let's say I have a few machines:

```java
//Test code of course.
public class Start{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println(Machine.COFFEE_GRINDER.getCatalogId());
    System.out.println(Machine.COFFEE_MACHINE.isOfType(Machine.BASIC_MACHINE)); 
    //The above should be true.
  }

  private enum Machine {
    BASIC_MACHINE (-1),
    BEVERAGE (-1),
    COFFEE(-1),
    COFFEE_GRINDER (5),
    COFFEE_MACHINE (6),
    GARDEN (-1),
    LAWN_MOWER (28);

    private final int catalogId;

    public int getCatalogId(){
      return catalogId;
    }

    public boolean isOfType(Machine to){
      return this == to;
    }

    Machine (int catalogId) {
      this.catalogId = catalogId;
    }
  }
}
```

In the example above there are Machines as they would appear in a catalog and have id numbers associated with them. There are also sections and sections of sections. So a BEVERAGE machine is still a BASIC_MACHINE. A COFFEE machine is still a BEVERAGE machine.

A few functions in a program will, before they perform their function, have to check if the Machine is actually a BEFERAGE machine. Both COFFEE_GRINDERs and COFFEE_MACHINEs from the catalog would check out and the function should go through.

The behaviour that I'm looking for is comparable to instanceof or the inheritance of abstract classes. Anyway a COFFEE_MACHINE is utimately a type of BASIC_MACHINE and I want to check that.

So:

```
Machine.COFFEE_MACHINE isa Machine.COFFEE
Machine.BEVERAGE isa MACHINE.BASIC_MACHINE
Machine.LAWN_MOWER isa Machine.GARDEN == Machine.BASIC_MACHINE
Machine.COFFEE_MACHINE isnota Machine.COFFEE_GRINDER
Machine.LAWN_MOWER isnota Machine.COFFEE
```

Comment: You just need to traverse the inheritance path starting from the most specialized `enum` value and check every step. Sounds rather trivial.

Comment: `VENDING` is undefined. Did you mean `BEVERAGE`?

Comment: You can't assign `Machine.COFFEE_MACHINE = Machine.COFFEE`, etc., because enum constants are constants. "Implement something?" It would help if you'd describe what "something" you're trying to accomplish. The title mentions inheritance, but except for anonymous body classes you can't subclass an enum, and you don't say what inheritance has to do with anything. You don't need to "check types" to know each constant, which _is_ an object, is of type `Machine`. As shown, your code won't compile. Please clarify what you want, and provide compilable code.

Comment: @LewBloch I don't think OP was trying to assign values there. I read that as OP's notation for showing inheritance, i.e. `COFFEE_MACHINE` "extends" `COFFEE`, which extends `BEVERAGE`, which extends `BASIC_MACHINE`, in the abstract sense, not the Java class inheritance sense. Question is badly written, and I thought as you, until I re-read the question. To me, it appears that OP want the equivalent of `instanceof` for comparing `Machine` enums, e.g. `COFFEE_MACHINE` is instance of `BEVERAGE`, but `LAWN_MOWER` is not instance of `COFFEE`.

Comment: You guys are right. I was vague. I hope this makes it a bit more clear. I also have a solution already, but I'm not sure if it is any good.

Comment: Sounds more like you want classes and instances than enums, or do you always have only one machine of each kind? Either way, define a class (or enum) hierarchy and add methods. Call these methods and let them do the right thing. Don't use `instanceof`; it's very un-OOP-ish. Google the 'tell, don't ask' principle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to mimic some inheritance using callbacks and a saved supertype.
I'm curious if this is the best way to go.

Implemented this would look like this:

```
//Test code of course.
public class Start{
  public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println(Machine.COFFEE_GRINDER.getCatalogId());
    System.out.println(Machine.COFFEE_MACHINE.isOfType(Machine.BASIC_MACHINE)); //Should be true.
  }

  private enum Machine {
    BASIC_MACHINE (-1),
    BEVERAGE (-1, BASIC_MACHINE),
    COFFEE(-1, BEVERAGE),
    COFFEE_GRINDER (5, COFFEE),
    COFFEE_MACHINE (6, COFFEE),
    GARDEN (-1, BASIC_MACHINE),
    LAWN_MOWER (28, GARDEN);

    private int catalogId;
    private Machine superMachine;

    public int getCatalogId(){
      return catalogId;
    }

    public Machine getSuperMachine(){
      return superMachine;
    }

    //With callback to superMachine (if present)
    public boolean isOfType(Machine to){
      return this == to || (getSuperMachine() != null && getSuperMachine().isOfType(to));
    }

    Machine (int catalogId) {
      this.catalogId = catalogId;
    }

    Machine (int catalogId, Machine superMachine) {
      this(catalogId);
      this.superMachine = superMachine;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your goal correctly, you want to express a network of relationships between the `enum` constants. Consider that inheritance is not necessarily aligned with the relationship you wish to express. Inheritance models an `is-a` relation between types; you want a `connects-to` relation between instances. Perhaps use a different terminology than "super/inherits", also, such as "owner-owns". You could embed a pointer to an `owner` instance in each constant and create an acyclic directed graph structure in a static initializer and the constructor.

```
public enum NetworkedMachine
{
BASIC_MACHINE(-1, null),
BEVERAGE(-1, BASIC_MACHINE),
COFFEE(-1, BASIC_MACHINE),
COFFEE_GRINDER(5, COFFEE),
COFFEE_MACHINE(6, COFFEE),
GARDEN(-1, BASIC_MACHINE),
LAWN_MOWER(28, GARDEN),
;

static final Map<NetworkedMachine, Set<NetworkedMachine>> owners;
static {
  Map<NetworkedMachine, Set<NetworkedMachine>> ownership = new HashMap<>();
  for (NetworkedMachine machine : values()) {
    ownership.put(machine, new HashSet<>());
  }
  for (NetworkedMachine machine : values()) {
    if (machine.owner != null) {
      ownership.get(machine.owner).add(machine);
    }
  }
  for (NetworkedMachine machine : values()) {
    Set<NetworkedMachine> owns = ownership.get(machine);
    ownership.put(machine, Collections.unmodifiableSet(owned));
  }
  owners = Collections.unmodifiableMap(ownership);
}

private final int catalogId;
private final NetworkedMachine owner;

NetworkedMachine(int catalogId, NetworkedMachine machine) {
  this.catalogId = catalogId;
  this.owner = machine;
}

public int getCatalogId() {
  return catalogId;
}

public NetworkedMachine getOwner() {
  return owner;
}

public Set<NetworkedMachine> getOwns() {
  return owners.get(this);
}

public boolean isOwned() {
  return owner != null;
}

}
```

Test output:

```
BASIC_MACHINE id: -1, owner: [null], owns: [GARDEN, BEVERAGE, COFFEE]
BEVERAGE id: -1, owner: [BASIC_MACHINE], owns: []
COFFEE id: -1, owner: [BASIC_MACHINE], owns: [COFFEE_GRINDER, COFFEE_MACHINE]
COFFEE_GRINDER id: 5, owner: [COFFEE], owns: []
COFFEE_MACHINE id: 6, owner: [COFFEE], owns: []
GARDEN id: -1, owner: [BASIC_MACHINE], owns: [LAWN_MOWER]
LAWN_MOWER id: 28, owner: [GARDEN], owns: []
```